# Updating a table in oracle with were conditions from other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update a record for a table and based on foreign key from other table..

```
Update table1 t1
Inner join  table2  t2 on t2.id = t1. Id 
Set t1. Name ='abc'
Where t2. User ='xyz';
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what went wrong or where you are stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax is not valid in Oracle use `MERGE`

```
MERGE INTO table2 trg 
using table1 src 
ON (trg.id = src.id 
   AND trg.user = 'xyz') 
WHEN matched THEN 
  UPDATE SET trg.NAME = 'abc';
```

Comment: @Yogesh - check now

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Exists`

```
Update table1
Set Name ='abc'
Where exists (select 1 
                from table2  t2 
               where t2.id = table1.Id 
                 and t2.User ='xyz');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query

```
MERGE INTO table1 t1
    USING table2  t2
     ON (t1.id = t2.id and t2.User='xyz') 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
update 
set t1.Name = 'abc';
```